# Page responsive tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a 3 column layout that is responsive to the page being resized.  I want it how [ESPN](http://www.espn.com/) does it. I would like it so that when it is a medium size it shows only two of the columns and a menu pops up on the top giving you the option to see the third column that just disappeared all on its own.  The best way to explain it is ESPN's website and resizing it left and right. I have tried using "onclick" with display none/block but it wasn't working with how I was writing it.

```css
.global-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
.center-container {
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
}
.left-container {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  margin-left: .5%;
}
.right-container {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
}
.responsive-menu {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.responsive-menu>ul {
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 44px;
}
.responsive-menu>ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.responsive-menu>ul>li {
  line-height: 44px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.responsive-menu>ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 44px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.responsive-menu>ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1E88E5;
  width: 60px;
}
.cards {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .right-container {
    display: none;
  }
  div.responsive-menu ul {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .global-container {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  #left-card {
    display: none;
  }
}
/*When smaller than 767 pixels*/

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu-button {
    display: block;
  }
  .top-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .left-container {
    display: none;
  }
  .center-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #left-card {
    display: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="left-card"><a href="#tab-1">Left</a>
    </li>
    <li id="center-card" class="active"><a href="#tab-2">Middle</a>
    </li>
    <li id="right-card"><a href="#tab-3">Right</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="global-container">
  <div class="left-container" id="tab-1">
    <div class="cards">Content for left container goes here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-container" id="tab-2">
    <div class="cards">Content for class center container Goes Here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-container" id="tab-3">
    <div class="cards">Content for right container goes here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ezc3sh39/ for easier use.

Comment: Plz post your JS code

Comment: @ChrisHappy https://jsfiddle.net/ezc3sh39/1/ Here is a jsfiddle with my javascript but it does not currently do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, tested and working.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezc3sh39/2/)

```js
$(function() {

  var $lef = $(".left-container");
  var $cen = $(".center-container");
  var $rig = $(".right-container");

  var $cards = $(".responsive-menu li");
  var $lefC = $("#left-card");
  var $cenC = $("#center-card");
  var $rigC = $("#right-card");

  function resize() {

    if (($(window).width() < 1000 || document.width < 1000) && $rigC.hasClass("active")) {
      $rig.show();
    } else {
      $rig.hide();
    };

    if (($(window).width() < 767 || document.width < 767) && !$rigC.hasClass("active")) {
      $lef.hide();
    } else if (($(window).width() > 767 || document.width > 767) && $lefC.hasClass("active")) {
      $cards.removeClass("active");
      $cenC.addClass("active");
      $cen.show();
    } else {
      $lef.show();
    };

    if ($(window).width() > 1000 || document.width > 1000) {
      $lef.add($cen).add($rig).show();
    }
  }
  resize();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    resize();
  });

  $cards.click(function() {
    $(".responsive-menu li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  $lefC.click(function() {
    $lef.addClass("show").fadeIn(1000);
    $cen.fadeOut(1000);
    $rig.removeClass("show").fadeOut(1000);
  });

  $rigC.click(function() {
    $lef.removeClass("show").fadeOut(1000);
    $cen.fadeOut(1000);
    $rig.addClass("show").fadeIn(1000);
  });

  $cenC.click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 767 || document.width < 767) {
      $lef.removeClass("show").fadeOut(1000);
      $cen.fadeIn(1000);
      $rig.removeClass("show").fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
      $lef.removeClass("show").fadeIn(1000);
      $cen.fadeIn(1000);
      $rig.removeClass("show").fadeOut(1000);
    }

  });


});
```

```css
.global-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.center-container {
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
}
.left-container {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  margin-left: .5%;
  display: none;
}
.right-container {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  display: none;
}
.responsive-menu {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.responsive-menu>ul {
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 44px;
}
.responsive-menu>ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.responsive-menu>ul>li {
  line-height: 44px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.responsive-menu>ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 44px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.responsive-menu>ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1E88E5;
  width: 60px;
}
.cards {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .global-container {
    margin-top: 75px;
  }
  div.responsive-menu ul {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .global-container {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  #left-card {
    display: none;
  }
  .right-container.show {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
/*When smaller than 767 pixels*/

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu-button {
    display: block;
  }
  .top-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .center-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #left-card {
    display: inherit;
  }
  .left-container.show {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="responsive-menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="left-card"><a href="#tab-1">Left</a>
    </li>
    <li id="center-card" class="active"><a href="#tab-2">Middle</a>
    </li>
    <li id="right-card"><a href="#tab-3">Right</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="global-container">
  <div class="left-container" id="tab-1">
    <div class="cards">LEFT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-container" id="tab-2">
    <div class="cards">CENTER</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-container" id="tab-3">
    <div class="cards">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery animations of [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/), and hiding them showing and hiding them with [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).